# fetch data from other server in create procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I have to create a procedure to fetch few values from database but I don't have access to write procedure on that server. So, I wanted to create that procedure on another server and fetch the values. I wanted to know if is it possible to create procedure to fetch values from any other server?.

Comment: And when you mention server, so is that a database? If so which database?

Comment: I mean server only. For the databases in the same server we can write 2 level name with USE. I am not getting what o do for different server. I cannot write as USE [server1].[database1]. It throws error that it cannot recognize server1.

Comment: 1) Which database are you using to have a stored procedure?
2) The target server where data resides, is that a database if so which one? 3) If target is a server in which format are the data being stored. You need to mention all these.

Comment: both are microsoft sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that in the target database you have read only access to fetch data. In that case you could

- Create a database link from the database where you would be creating
  stored procedure.
- Read the data from target database using the database link (db link).

Once you are able to get the data from target database you could do any manipulation you would want to. For creating database link in sql server you could check [this](http://dba010.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/how-to-create-database-link-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: This is called a "linked server" in SQL Server land, not a db link.

Comment: @SebastianMeine oh I see, I am from Oracle background. Thanks for that.